# self sizing table view with different constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

i am trying to make self sizing table view. the table view cell before editing is like this

[image]

there are 2 type of post in this table view cells. a post without image, and a post with an image. I want to make that second post 'Testting' which is only contains a text to shrink up using self sizing table view. I use this line of code in the `viewDidLoad`

```
  // to set the dynamic height of table view
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

but the result it seems ugly. I think have used the right auto layout constraint before implementing self sizing table view. but i don't know what went wrong in here. it seems that it follows/depends the height of the image even though the image is not there

[image]

the autolayout contraints I used is like this
[image]

username label constraints

[image]

avatar image constraints

[image]

post text label constraints

[image]

i suspect because it has 2 different constraint, one with image and the other doesn't have image. so how do i fix that ?

Comment: "I have used the right auto layout constraint before implementing self sizing table view" Obviously that's false. Remember, for this to work, the cell must size _itself_ using constraints from the inside out. However, you don't say anything about what your constraints _are_, so your question is pointless.

Comment: "the table view cell before editing is like this "  Nobody knows where your cell data comes from.

Comment: @matt sorry, I have added the constraints now. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have `heightForRowAt` implemented?  Also, are you getting messages about your layout in the Xcode console?? If not, what happens when you use the View Debugger? Does it report any ambiguity issues?

Comment: no i have not implemented heightForRowAt

Comment: no i don't have any issue at all in debug area and also no layout issue :)

Comment: Try this Give your post label to bottom constraints with Greater than equal ,  your imageview's bottom should be greater than equal relation. When you need to hide Image set height & Width Constraint to 0

Comment: @Alexa289 You should create two custom cell one with image and other one without image.Then you can set constraints individually in both cells